# Convert Video Format to save space?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

The MOV video files from my Canon S110 are huge files. A 20 second clip is 90MB. They are 1080HD videos. Is this simply the nature of HD video size, or is there another format I could convert them to which would save on space?

I'd like to use something like FFmpeg to convert all the videos I've taken. Could someone suggest a format and some settings that would mostly maintain the video quality, while saving some space for storage or sharing?

Comment: Above post should hopefully answer all your questions. If not, ping me here.

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorry I didn't see that one before posting.